# ElasticSearch Multiple Data Directories, choose where to place the index

Tags: java, elasticsearch, configuration

I'm running ElasticSearch over multiple servers. All servers are equal, all have 2 disks: one SSD, and one HDD. Needless to say, the SSD is faster yet smaller.

I know you can set multiple data directories in ES by added the paths to `elasticsearch.yml`. But, by default, (from what I've found) ES automatically chooses which data directory to take based on the percentage of disk space available.

Some indices are more important to me than others, say newer ones (those that get queried a lot) need to be on the SSD, and those that will be queried less can be on HDD.

What do I need to do to get this done - if possible at this time?
Add index to path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible in Elasticsearch. Yes, you can specify multiple data paths, but those cannot be "assigned" to indices.

At the moment, ES will stripe the data on a file level to all the data paths, this means shards will be spread over all the paths:

> Path to directory where to store index data allocated for this node.
>
> path.data: /path/to/data
>
> Can optionally include more than one location, causing data to be striped across
>   the locations (a la RAID 0) on a file level, favouring locations with most free
>    space on creation. For example:
>
> path.data: /path/to/data1,/path/to/data2

In 2.0 on the other hand [this will change](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9498) but you will still not be able to have an index on a data path and another index on another data path.

At the moment, the only solution for your use case is to have SSDs on "hot" nodes and HDDs on "cold" nodes, meaning one ES node with SSD and one ES node with HDD: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/retiring-data.html#migrate-indices

Comment: That sucks (not your answer, but the lack of possibility (I'll get over it :-) ), but was my backup plan... So I'll need 2 nodes per server, one on the SSD, and one on the HDD... Migrate the indices that are not 'hot' anymore to a 'cold' node... I must say, the `migrate-indices` link pretty much exactly described my issue (except for the type of data, but that's irrelevant)... Any expert tips on this?

Comment: One tip: if you add two nodes on the same physical machine, don't forget to set [`processors` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-threadpool.html#processors) accordingly otherwise the thread pools each node will create will be based on the total CPU count of the machine.

Comment: That's the kind of tip I meant... I see how that can become unfortunate :p... Thanks!